# Who do I keep getting "None" as a result of running my Python code in IDLE?

Tags: python, mysql

Might be a stupid question sorry. So I have a table in my DB with pic column, there are pictures there. I need to get one random one and post it through my Telegram bot when asked. I've checked connection with DB through MySQL workbench, its fine so the code is the problem. Here it is:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="***",
  port='3306',
  user="***",
  password="***",
  database ="***"
)

cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

query = ("SELECT pic FROM pets ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")

result = cursor.execute(query)
print(result)

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

When I run it in IDLE, I get "None" and nothing else.

Is is because I need to somehow specify how to show this type of data (picture)? In MySQL workbench result of query is just bytes so I thought it would show smth like that

I've tried converting result into some type of data but got this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/olina/Desktop/test.py", line 19, in <module>
> turnintobyte = bytes(result)
> TypeError: cannot convert 'NoneType' object to bytes

So looks like it doesn't get any data at all from query but I don't get why. Help pls I'm stuck

Comment: What tutorial says that that should give you a result?

Comment: `cursor.execute()` doesn't return anything. If you want the data that was selected, you need to use `cursor.fetchone()` or `cursor.fetchall()`

Comment: @Barmar The [guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-select.html) for querying disagrees. It just iterates over the cursor.

Comment: @KellyBundy using the cursor as an iterator is equivalent to a loop that calls `cursor.fetchone()`. But it's still not using the result of `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: @KellyBundy I've used the guide for querying. At the end it says "the output should look like this" and that's why I thought the example code should be enough :(

Comment: @Barmar ty for clarifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One might expect that the `cursor.execute()` would return a value of some kind, but it fact it does not.

The data is obtainable inside the `cursor` itself.

If you take a look at the example in the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) you will see this.

There is no return, just an execution, and if there is a return then it is an `iterator` like this:

```py
cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=False)
iterator = cursor.execute(operation, params=None, multi=True)
```

This is why `result` will show nothing.

To get the result to return something, then would require `cursor.fetchone()` or `cursor.fetchall()` (as one of the comments has suggested) or loop over the result as an iterator (as per the example) etc...

Comment: ahh thanks! i've been following another guide from mysql, just for querying, and there were no mentions of fetching. ty for explaining

Comment: The form where it returns an iterator is only used when you're executing multiple queries in a single call. The iterator gets you a cursor for each query's results, and then you need to do nested iteration or `fetchXXX()` on that to get the rows. That option is generally best ignored.

Comment: You are welcome.  i have come across this issue before _expecting a return when there was no return_. So it is useful to remember this.